# Render Sketchup model API

Tags: c++, qt, sketchup

I am looking for a SDK/API for rendering a Sektchup (.skp) model file in a Qt application. I've found the [Sketchup SDK](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/su-api/) but no hint on rendering.

All I need would be a still-image in one of the standard perspectives, but panning, rotating and zooming would be of course great additions.

Answer (score 1):

Some more googling turned up a a way to extract the thumbnail PNG from the Sketchup-Model file without any SDK or other libraryies. This satisifies my needs to now.

It turns out the thumbnail is simply a PNG embedded in the SKP file, so parsing a `QFile` and looking for the first PNG signature `0x89504e470d0a1a0a` is all that is needed. I then pass the correctly positioned `QFile` to a `QImageReader` to read the PNG and display it.

The code is reasonably simple and I could share it, but I'm unsure whether pasting it here is really considered good style. Opinions?

Comment: Of course answers that include code are good! Please edit the answer to remove the last paragraph (the question) and add the code :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a **rendering engine** (*API for rendering 3D vector graphics* / *Rasterization API* / *Game Engine* / other types of *rendering engine*).

- Low level examples - OpenGL, WebGL, DirectX.
- High level examples - Ogre3D, Three.js, Unity Engine.

The *SketchUp SDK* only provides interface to read/write a SketchUp file.

You will need to use the *SketchUp C API* to extract information about the model (**triangulated meshes**, **textures**, **camera position** **...**).

Then feed those information into the *rendering engine* of your choice to render your model.

Comment: In the case that you only need a 2d projection, you can write code to extract meshes and calculate the 2d projection. Then use some 2D graphics library to render the result. (Be aware that the development time of this will probably be very long.)